# Capybara Regex with Find

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to write something generic in the interim for an app that's being developed.  The header elements are constantly changing between h2 and h3, and are causing unnecessary failures.  I want something a little more specific that expect(page).to have_text ...

What I want to do is write a find command in Capybara that will place a regex for a digit in the code. Like so:

```
def locate_headers(arg)
  header = find(/h(\d+)/, text: arg)
 end
```

I'm hoping this would find the H element on screen that matches the text.

I get the following error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

I don't have a lot of experience with Regex.  Is what I want to do, possible?

Thanks

Comment: You can use something like https://regex101.com/ to build a regex on the fly- that might help?

Comment: I've been using Rubular.com and I have a working Regex but Capybara / Selenium are throwing an error

Comment: I'm thinking that Capybara doesn't allow a regex to be used for the element part of the method, only the options like text / value etc

Comment: Something like `find('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6', text: arg)` should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS selectors don’t support regex matching but they do support OR matching with the CSS comma. This means you can get what you want with

```
def locate_header(arg)
  header = find('h2, h3', text: arg)
end
```

which will find either an `<h2>` or `<h3>` element containing the given text

Comment: I've been using this library for almost 2 years, and this is the first I've heard of this... wow!

Answer (score 0):

`find` takes an **CSS selector** as argument, not a RegEx one. Hence the "illegal selector".

Having this in mind, there's `:header` selector that selects headers only. However, I am not sure if it is compatible with Capaybara [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_header.asp)

Comment: I have given that a go and you're right, it's not a locator option for Capybara.  Thank you for the answer though

Comment: The `:header` selector is jQuery only and is not supported by browsers natively.  The natively supported CSS equivalent would be "h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6"